# Automatic role assignment in discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In a project with friends I decided to make a bot by myself, I was given the need for the bot to assign a random range among 2 already existing, but it does not work, it does not even give me an error.

```
if (command === 'rol') {
        module.exports = (client, member) => {
            const logChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "log");
            var list = Array("rol1", "rol2");
            var alet = Math.floor(Math.random()*(list.length));              
            var op = list[alet];
            if (op === "rol1") {
                let member = member.user;
                let rol = "rol1";
                let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", rol);
                miembro.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
                logChannel.send(console.error);
            } else if (op === "rol2") {
                let member = member.user;
                var rol = "rol2";
                let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", rol);
                miembro.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
                logChannel.send(console.error);
            }
            else {
                logChannel.send(console.error);
            } 
        }

    };
```

Comment: There appears to be a couple of spelling mistakes, as well as some weird syntax in here. You use `miembro.addRole...` which doesn't work as `miembro` is not defined anywhere in your code here. The weird syntax comes in with the `module.exports` part at the start of your function, if this is part of a block of `if` statements, you can remove the `module.exports` stuff since this is already a function being run and just causes the file to export the function instead of running it.

Answer (score 1):

Might be just that you need to remove the brakets here:

`var alet = Math.floor(Math.random()*(list.length));`

so it will become:

`var alet = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);`

I also think you don't need to have 2 if statements, you could just:

```
if (command === 'rol') {
    module.exports = (client, member) => {
        const logChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "log");
        var list = Array("rol1", "rol2");
        var alet = Math.floor(Math.random()*(list.length));              
        var op = list[alet];
            let member = member.user;
            let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", op);
            miembro.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
            logChannel.send(console.error);

}
};
```

Give it a try.